# How do I call my function that returns an array of pointers? C++

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers, syntax

Completely new to pointers, so I apologize for the novice question. I am receiving a conversion error when trying to call my function.
This function is supposed to return a pointer to an updated array that contains 1 at the end.

```
int* appendList(int x, int &arraySize, int *list)
{
    arraySize++;
    int *array2 = new int[arraySize];
    for(int i=0; i < arraySize-1; i++)
    {
        array2[i] = list[i-1];
    }
    array2[arraySize]=x;

    return array2;
}
```

My main function is as follows.

```
int main()
{
    int size=0;
    int *list;
    cout << "Please enter the size of your array: ";
    cin >> size;
    list = new int[size];
    cout << "\nPlease enter the numbers in your list seperated by spaces: ";
    for(int i=0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cin >> list[i];
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << "The array you entered is listed below\n ";
    for(int i=0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << setw(3) << list[i];
    }

    list = appendList(1, size, list);
    for(int i=0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << setw(3) << list[i];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The call to function appendList results in a conversion error for argument three, but I'm not sure why?  The function parameters must stay the way they are.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You use `cout `and `setw` without `std::`, so I guess you declared a `using namespace std` above. Then the `list` variable name may have collision with `std::list<T>`. Try use other name.

Comment: What other name could I use?

Comment: list1, my_list, ary, or some name different to c++ keyword or STL template. Or you may try not to use `using namespace std;` to expose all names from the std::.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A mistake that I found in your code.

```
 int* appendList(int x,int &arraySize,int *list)
        {
        arraySize++;
        int *array2=new int[arraySize];
        for(int i=0;i<arraySize-1;i++)
        {
            array2[i]=list[i-1];//this is incorrect because for i=0 it becomes list[-1] which is wrong
        }
        array2[arraySize]=x;

        return array2;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, I haven't even been able to debug it since I can't get the function to call correctly.